# Redis/AWS Airflow Managed Service - zsets are returned as type string, prohibiting the use of zrange methods (aioredis Python Client)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, redis, airflow

I am using Managed Apache Airflow (v 1.10.12) in AWS to create a DAG for a Redis database.

Data is currently being fed into Redis using python with the following code:

`redis.zadd(timestamp_key, {message.id: arrow.get(message.time).timestamp()})`

`timestamp_key` would then be a ZSET containing `message.id` as the value and a timestamp as the score.

To retrieve these values and scores, I first use `redis.scan_iter("matchingstring:*")` to create an iterator of all `timestamp_key`s, then use `redis.zrangebyscore(timestamp_key, min_value, max_value)` to iterate over each element, which is the part that doesn't work.

This gives a `ERROR - WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value` because `redis.type(timestamp_key)` returns the value to be a string instead of a ZSET, which prevents the use of any ZRANGE methods.

I have had success with running this code locally (not using Airflow).

Comment: Are you using the built-in Redis Hook?

Comment: I'm using the built-in hook to get connection info but it only has two methods (.get_conn() and .key_exists()) - so I'm using the connection info to establish a connection using aioredis using .from_url().